# Use concatenated string in Excel formula to get the cell value

Tags: excel

I have a sheet named Vessel Reading 1. I want to read the value of the cell D4 into another sheet. `'Vessel Reading 1'!D4` gives me the value properly.

But, I want to be able to get the latest number instead of just 'Vessel Reading 1'. E.g. if I have five sheets named 'Vessel Reading 1 to 5', I want to read the value from sheet named 'Vessel Reading 5'. Basically, `'Vessel Reading 1'!D4` should be changed to `'Vessel Reading N'!D4` where N is the latest sheet.

```
CONCATENATE("Vessel Reading ",RIGHT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))),1))
```

Above sheet gives me the sheet name that I want. E.g. if I am in sheet 5, it gives me 'Vessel Reading 5', and if I am in sheet 2, it gives me 'Vessel Reading 2'.

So, clearly, most of the work is already in place. Sadly, when I use

```
'CONCATENATE("Vessel Reading ",RIGHT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))),1))'!D4
```

it throws an error. Now I am not sure what am I missing in this formula.

Edit:

Basically, I need a way to put the result of concatenate as a string to create cell reference.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? And is `filename` supposed to be some kind of placeholder or do you really want to insert the String "filename"?

Comment: Any advantage using `CONCATENATE` function instead of `&` operator ? I could never understand the reason M$ had to add this function, specially the way it is implemented. If only it could handle `Ranges` !

Comment: "filename" string will give you the name of the sheet you are on. Basically using this to get the current sheet's last character (e.g. sheet names are "Bunker Tanker Reading 1", "Bunker Tanker Reading 2" and so on). That way, I can read which particular copy of the sheet, it is. So, my formula will read "Vessel Reading X" sheet, where X is the last character of the current sheet (i.e. "Bunker Tanker Reading X").

Comment: @iDevlop I am not sure if there is any advantage. And tbh I don't even worry about it. Excel formulas has always been "do it because clients likes it this way" thing. I would much rather create a basic app with proper forms and use proper validation than excel formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your formula for the sheet name in A1 then you can use this formula to find out value of D4 cell from that sheet.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",A1,"'!D4"))
```

You can replace the A1 in the formula above with the code you created to find out the sheet and all will be in single formula. Full formula would look like

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",CONCATENATE("Vessel Reading ",RIGHT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))),1)),"'!D4"))
```

Comment: That works. But, now I have to hide the cell A1 too. :/

Comment: you dont have to hide the cell, you just have to put the formulas together. I didnt want to, because it looks quite long and confusing - I will update the answer

Comment: Never mind. I copied the value to some random cell, like zz11. Then I hid that column. :)

Comment: Well, I guess putting the full formula in one place is much better.